# Preconditioning matrix

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to solve $Ax=b$ system, but the conditioning of $A$ is bad.
After some research, I found that the conditioning of $A$ can be improved by multiplying the system by a preconditioning matrix $P$ such as :

$Ax = b \Rightarrow P^{-1}Ax = P^{-1}b$

Can I calculate $P$? how?

I tried the case when $P^{-1}=A^{-1}$ and I found $x=b$, is there someone who can explain me that result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $P^{-1}$ to come as close as possible to being an inverse of $A$, but you also want $P^{-1} b$ to be easy to compute.  These desires conflict with each other.  Two extreme cases are $P = A$ and $P = I$.  In the first case, the resulting system $x = P^{-1}b$ is trivial to solve, but computing $P^{-1} b$ is as difficult as solving the original system.  In the other case ($P = I$), $P^{-1} b = b$ is trivial to compute, but the new system $P^{-1} A x = P^{-1} b$
is no easier to solve than the original system.  What we want is something in between these two extreme cases.

Trefethen's really good book Numerical Linear Algebra has a survey of popular preconditioners at the end.  They say that finding a good preconditioner is difficult, and usually depends on your specific application.

Comment: @Bek A good preconditioner clusters the eigenvalues around the minimal number of distinct numbers (ideally 1) as possible. This is highly dependent on the matrix $A$, but preconditioners based on incomplete factorisations (either $LU$ or cholesky) can be helpful initially. This should be how you decide on the precondition between the two extreme types of preconditioners littleO describes.